# c# Xamarin UITextField setting the cursor position

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uitextfield

I need to position the cursor of a UITextField in the exact same position as another previous text field. I get the position of the cursor in the first text field as `nint index = txtToField.GetOffsetFromPosition(txtToField.BeginningOfDocument, txtToField.SelectedTextRange.Start);`, which correctly gets the number of characters from the beginning of the textfield my cursor is currently in. After some research, and using the question below:

[Setting cursor position of UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414942/setting-cursor-position-of-uitextfield)

I have tried to implement the question's solution to setting the cursor position in a textfield, using the index I previously got. This doesn't work, and after making the text field the first responder and running:

```
txtTo.BecomeFirstResponder();
UITextPosition positionSet = txtTo.GetPosition(txtTo.BeginningOfDocument, position);
txtTo.SelectedTextRange = txtTo.GetTextRange(positionSet, positionSet);
```

It automatically puts your cursor at the end of the UITextField. Further, I attempted to check if the `SelectedTextRange` method worked as expected, however when trying to set all of the text in the text field as selected:

```
txtTo.BecomeFirstResponder();
txtTo.SelectedTextRange = txtTo.GetTextRange(txtTo.BeginningOfDocument, txtTo.EndOfDocument);
```

It also automatically puts the cursor to the end of the UITextField, which is a standard behaviour for `BecomeFirstResponder()`. Does `SelectedTextRange` not work in this current version of Xamarin?

I am using version 7.6.10 (build 27) of Xamarin and Xamarin.iOS version 12.0.0.15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:** 
The cursor is at the end of the text in dafault.When you init a UITextField and set it as FirstResponder in the method `ViewDidLoad`.The view is still not finish init.

**Solution:**
You can call these method in the method `EditingStarted` .And don't forget set the delegate.

```
public partial clas xxxViewController:UIViewController,IUITextFieldDelegate

txtTo.WeakDelegate=this;

[Export("textFieldDidBeginEditing:")]
public void EditingStarted(UITextField textField)
{
  NSRange range = new NSRange(index, 0);
  UITextPosition start = textField.GetPosition(textField.BeginningOfDocument, range.Location);
  UITextPosition end = textField.GetPosition(start, range.Length);
  textField.SelectedTextRange = textField.GetTextRange(start, end);
}
```

If you do want to call them in `ViewDidLoad` .You can set a delay (for example 0.1s).

```
//...
this.PerformSelector(new Selector("MoveCursorPosition:"),txtTo,0.1);
//...

[Export("MoveCursorPosition:")]
public void MoveCursorPosition(UITextField textField)
{
  NSRange range = new NSRange(index, 0);
  UITextPosition start = textField.GetPosition(textField.BeginningOfDocument, range.Location);
  UITextPosition end = textField.GetPosition(start, range.Length);
  textField.SelectedTextRange = textField.GetTextRange(start, end);
}
```

Comment: I never start editing this UITextField though. This is called in the ViewDidLoad directly after the UITextField has become a first responder.

Comment: the method will been called when the field BecomeFirstResponder , you can have a try

Comment: Ok thank you. On a more technical note, why would the code that I have used not work in the ViewDidLoad but will in the EditingStarted method?

Comment: First let me know if your problem has been solved.And then I can tell you more detail.

Comment: Look at my update answer.If your issue been solved.You can mark it as answer .